# How to stop EMR Cluster without terminating it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, emr

I know it is possible to stop individual EC2 instances, but what about the EMR cluster?

If I stop all EC2 instances comprising EMR cluster, would I still be billed?

Answer (score 5):

At this time there is not a way to STOP and EMR cluster in the same sense you can with EC2 instances. The EMR cluster uses instance-store volumes and the EC2 start/stop feature relies on the use of EBS volumes which are not appropriate for high-performance, low-latency HDFS utilization.

The best way to simulate this behavior is to store the data in S3 and then just ingest as a start up step of the cluster then save back to S3 when done.

Comment: "cannot stop" is this a feature by design or it is a bug that need to fixed. One can argue that EMR is just the computing engine and make hdfs ephemeral is a good habit people to wrap their head around so code and data are backedup. Meanwhile, EMR is like a giant server that one can argue since you can stop an EC2, why shouldn't you just make it easy to "pause".